# Is there any fast formula to find the biggest area of a general quadrangle (hexahedron) given by N points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, shapes, modeling

I am using pythom 3.6 and I have came across a problem. There are given n points by x and y coordinates (n is from 4 to 200) and I need to find the 4 points from those n which form the biggest general quadrangle (any convex shape formed by 4 points).

I can think of a solution including 4 for cycles with calculating the area of the quadrangle given by point in the for cycles, but it is extremaly slow. Do you know about anything faster?

The point are given like this:

```
B = np.array([[ 1., 2.], [ 0., 0.], [ 1., 3.], [ -5., 6.], [ -6., 3.], [ 1., 5.], [ -1., 2.], [ 1., -3.], [ 4., 2.]])
```

The next level is when I get N points given by x, y and z coordinates (N is between 8 and 500) and I should find the biggest (in volume) hexahedron (the shape defined by 8 points) - I have no idea of the solution.

There is no need for right angles, just shapes defined by 4 (8) points. Any suggestions?

---

Background:
I have quite complex 3D models of building which I need to simplify to one specific program for computations. The details on the building are not needed. All information about the buildings is in file.obj exported from Blender.

Comment: Does it have to be the biggest quadrilateral? What about in the top 10?

Comment: Well, it should be the biggest to represent the building's base as much as possible. Imagine you have a building with a general shape of its base. You need to approximate its shape by general quadrangle. If the base has a complex shape, then it shoul be easy. If it is "L" or "U" shaped, I would like to take the free space as the building too (doing from "U" an "O" and form "L" some weird shape approximation).

Comment: I see. I think if you find a central point among your coordinates, then divide the points into 4 quadrants (8 if you have x,y,z coordinates), you could find the point in each quadrant that is furthest from your central point, and then use those points to find the area

Comment: That is a good point but it won't work in general cases. If you devide the area to 4 quadrants in a bad way (so two of the desired points are in one) you will get smaller and not precise approximation. But it is a good way of thinking. Thank you.

Comment: I've just finished testing that theory and got an area about 2/3 the max area after iteratively going through a list of 10 points. It seemed like it would help.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I will test the theory with a rotating quadrants let's say per 1 degree until 90° to find the most distant points from the centre. For each rotation I will find the most distant points in each quadrant and calculate the area. The biggest area should be hopefully close to the area. Thank you. I will write wheather the test is succesful.

Comment: Perhaps vertices of the biggest area quadtrilateral belong to the convex hull of all points. If so, rotating calipers might help at the next step

Comment: Well thank you all for the answers. It is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer for the 2D and 3D problem is similar. Because it are buildings, we can split the 3D model to two 2D models with the base of the building and the roof (and anything between is considered as roof too).

Then we are searching for the quadrangle to approximate the points in a (approximately) plane. We need to find the centre (not by mean from all points, but (max+min)/2 in both directons). We move the origin to the centre by calculation of the points - centre. The points then should be devided by quadrants (x>0 & y>0, x<0, & y>0, x<0, & y<0, x>0, & y<0) and for each quadrant we calculate the most distant point (if there is nan, we take the origin [0,0]).

Using the Shoelace formula we calculate the area taken by those 4 points from each quadrants keeping that value.
After that we rotate the points around the origin by 1 degree up to 90 degrees. Each time we calculate the area and we are searching for the maximum area. The points shoving the maximum area are the desired points.
The code (I know it is not smooth code, can be optimized. But it works!!):

```
def getCorners(points):
    maxPoint = np.max(points[:,0])
    mayPoint = np.max(points[:,1])
    minPoint = np.min(points[:,0])
    miyPoint = np.min(points[:,1])
    meanPoint = np.array([(maxPoint + minPoint)/2, (mayPoint + miyPoint)/2])
    normPoints = points[:,0:2] - meanPoint[0:2]
    areaMaximum = -1
    finID1 = 0
    finID2 = 1
    finID3 = 2
    finID4 = 3
    numrot = 360

    for alpha in range(0,numrot):
        topright = np.where((normPoints[:,0] > 0) & (normPoints[:,1] > 0))
        topleft = np.where((normPoints[:,0] < 0) & (normPoints[:,1] > 0))
        bottomleft = np.where((normPoints[:,0] < 0) & (normPoints[:,1] < 0))
        bottomright = np.where((normPoints[:,0] > 0) & (normPoints[:,1] < 0))

        q1 = normPoints[topright]
        q2 = normPoints[topleft]
        q3 = normPoints[bottomleft]
        q4 = normPoints[bottomright]

        if len(q1) == 0:
            q1 = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])
        if len(q2) == 0:
            q2 = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])
        if len(q3) == 0:
            q3 = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])
        if len(q4) == 0:
            q4 = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])

        D1 = q1[:,0]*q1[:,0] + q1[:,1]*q1[:,1]
        D2 = q2[:,0]*q2[:,0] + q2[:,1]*q2[:,1]
        D3 = q3[:,0]*q3[:,0] + q3[:,1]*q3[:,1]
        D4 = q4[:,0]*q4[:,0] + q4[:,1]*q4[:,1]

        ID1 = np.argmax(D1)
        ID2 = np.argmax(D2)
        ID3 = np.argmax(D3)
        ID4 = np.argmax(D4)
        vertices = [[q1[ID1,0],q1[ID1,1]],[q2[ID2,0],q2[ID2,1]],[q3[ID3,0],q3[ID3,1]],[q4[ID4,0],q4[ID4,1]]]
        area = polygonArea(vertices)

        if area > areaMaximum:
            areaMaximum = area
            if len(topright[0]) == 0:
                finID1 = 0
            else:
                finID1 = topright[0][ID1]
            if len(topleft[0]) == 0:
                finID2 = 0
            else:
                finID2 = topleft[0][ID2]
            if len(bottomleft[0]) == 0:
                finID3 = 0
            else:
                finID3 = bottomleft[0][ID3]
            if len(bottomright[0]) == 0:
                finID4 = 0
            else:
                finID4 = bottomright[0][ID4]

        # rotate
        for opi in range(0,len(normPoints)):
            normPoints[opi] = rotate_origin_only(normPoints[opi], 90/numrot/180*np.pi)

    return [finID1,finID2,finID3,finID4]

def rotate_origin_only(xy, radians):
    """Only rotate a point around the origin (0, 0)."""
    x, y = xy
    xx = x * math.cos(radians) + y * math.sin(radians)
    yy = -x * math.sin(radians) + y * math.cos(radians)

    return xx, yy

def polygonArea(vertices):
    #A function to apply the Shoelace algorithm
    numberOfVertices = len(vertices)
    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0

    for i in range(0,numberOfVertices-1):
        sum1 = sum1 + vertices[i][0] *  vertices[i+1][1]
        sum2 = sum2 + vertices[i][1] *  vertices[i+1][0]

    #Add xn.y1
    sum1 = sum1 + vertices[numberOfVertices-1][0]*vertices[0][1]   
    #Add x1.yn
    sum2 = sum2 + vertices[0][0]*vertices[numberOfVertices-1][1]   

    area = abs(sum1 - sum2) / 2
    return area
```

Answer (score 1):

Build [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of all points.

Then find the largest area quadtrilateral with vertices belonging to the hull.
If hull count N is small, you can just check all diagonals.

Otherwise consider using of more advanced algorithms like this: [Maximum-Area Quadrilateral in a Convex Polygon, Revisited](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00681.pdf)